# Multi List Compare with single list Linq Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have three classes

```
class students
{
   int age
   string name
   List<Courses> Courses
}
class Courses
{
   int courses_id
   string Name
}
class Subject_Name
{
   string Name
}
```

i have a list of students and list of subject_names i want to write a linq query which return those students if there is any
single subject match with their courses.

Sql query will be like

```
select * from students 
inner join Courses on students.Courses_id=Courses.Courses_id
and Courses.Name in (select name from subject_Name)
```

Any one for help.

Comment: `students` does not have `Courses_id`. Are your entity classes correct? Or are you asking how to correct them?

Comment: Also, I cannot see any classes referencing `Subject_Name`

Comment: yes these are entity class

Comment: subject name is separate stand alone class

Comment: Which data access technology are you using? Entity Framework?

Comment: .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server.

Comment: So you are using ADO.NET directly? Can you provide sample code of how you communicate with the database?

Comment: `students.Courses_id`, but `List<Courses> Courses`? You're making this very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like the following:

```
string[] subject_names = {"subject1" , "subject2"};

var result = students_table
        .Where(s => s.Courses.Any(c => subject_names.Contains(c.Name)))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: You can avoid the string[] with `students_table.Where(s => s.Courses.Any(c => subject_names_table.Select(subject => subject.Name).Contains(c.Name))).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqAnswer
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();

        public void AddCourse(Course course)
        {
            Courses.Add(course);
        }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; } = new List<Subject>();

        public void AddSubject(Subject subject)
        {
            Subjects.Add(subject);
        }
    }

    public class Subject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student { Age = 18, Name = "A" },
                new Student { Age = 19, Name = "B" },
                new Student { Age = 21, Name = "C" },
                new Student { Age = 22, Name = "D" },
                new Student { Age = 20, Name = "E" }
            };
            var courses = new List<Course>
            {
                new Course { Id = 1, Name = "C1" },
                new Course { Id = 2, Name = "C2" },
                new Course { Id = 3, Name = "C3" },
                new Course { Id = 4, Name = "C4" }
            };
            var subjects = new List<Subject>
            {
                new Subject { Name = "S1" },
                new Subject { Name = "S2" },
                new Subject { Name = "S3" }
            };
            students[0].AddCourse(courses[0]);
            students[0].AddCourse(courses[2]);
            students[1].AddCourse(courses[3]);
            students[2].AddCourse(courses[0]);
            students[2].AddCourse(courses[3]);
            students[3].AddCourse(courses[2]);
            students[4].AddCourse(courses[1]);

            courses[0].AddSubject(subjects[0]);
            courses[0].AddSubject(subjects[1]);
            courses[1].AddSubject(subjects[0]);
            courses[2].AddSubject(subjects[1]);
            courses[2].AddSubject(subjects[2]);
            courses[3].AddSubject(subjects[2]);

            var studentsWithSubjectS2 = from student in students
                                        from course in student.Courses
                                        where course.Subjects.IndexOf(subjects[2]) >= 0
                                        select student;
            foreach(var studentWithSubjectS2 in studentsWithSubjectS2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{studentWithSubjectS2.Name}, Age={studentWithSubjectS2.Age}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sir there is not relation between subject and courses, subjects is stand alone class.

Comment: Ok, I was too fast. I thought the same Subject (like Algebra) could be used in more than one course.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming EntityFramework and giving `Student` a `StudentId` Property, here is my $.02 try:

```
IList<int> studentIds = (from student in _context.Students
            from cource in
                student.Courses.Where(cource => _context.Subjects.Select(p => p.Name).ToList().Contains(cource.Name))
            select student.StudentId).ToList();

IQueryable<Student> selected = _context.Students.Where(p => studentIds.Distinct().Contains(p.StudentId));
```